# stop footer from coming up when softkeyboard up : android

Tags: android, xml, footer, android-softkeyboard

I was wondering how to stop the soft keyboard from making my footer come up and cover up the login button

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">

    <!--  Header  Starts-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
                  android:paddingTop="5dip"
                  android:paddingBottom="5dip">
        <!-- Logo Start-->
        <!--<ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"-->
                   <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                   <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                   <!--android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>-->
        <!-- Logo Ends -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--  Header Ends -->
    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="40dip"
                  android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Footer Ends -->

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">
        <!--  Username Label -->
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#372c24"
                  android:text="Username"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_username"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                  android:textColor="#000"/>
        <!-- Password Label -->
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#372c24"
                  android:text="Password"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_password"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:password="true"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                  android:textColor="#000"/>
        <!-- Login Button -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:text="Login"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Login Form Ends -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this attribute to your activity will help you.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

If you want more detail about this attribute, please reference this:

[wsoft](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 0):

Put this into the application manifist file inside your activity tag :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```